# Is it possible to divide my crowdsale contract into multiple files in order to solve gas issue?

Tags: contract-development, truffle, gas, crowdsale

I'm trying to deploy a crowdsale contract, which is using open zeppelin, on ropsten network but I got gas related error. The error says "please check your gas amount". How can I solve it? I think this contract is very simple crowdsale contract. Thus, I believe I don't need to separate to multiple files. I did not try it on mainnet.

This is all what I did

```
$ mkdir /tmp/manatoken-infra
$ cd /tmp/manatoken-infra
$ truffle init
$ npm install ethereumjs-wallet bip39 web3-provider-engine@8.6.1 web3@0.18.4 zeppelin-solidity --save
$ vi ./truffle.js 
$ vi ./contracts/GustavoCoin.sol
$ vi ./contracts/GustavoCoinCrowdsale.sol
$ vi ./migrations/2_deploy_contracts.js
$ truffle compile
$ truffle deploy --network ropsten
```

truffle.js

```
var bip39 = require("bip39");
var hdkey = require('ethereumjs-wallet/hdkey');
var ProviderEngine = require("web3-provider-engine");
var WalletSubprovider = require('web3-provider-engine/subproviders/wallet.js');
var Web3Subprovider = require("web3-provider-engine/subproviders/web3.js");
var Web3 = require("web3");
var FilterSubprovider = require('web3-provider-engine/subproviders/filters.js');

// Get our mnemonic and create an hdwallet
var mnemonic = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
var hdwallet = hdkey.fromMasterSeed(bip39.mnemonicToSeed(mnemonic));

// Get the first account using the standard hd path.
var wallet_hdpath = "m/44'/60'/0'/0/";
var wallet = hdwallet.derivePath(wallet_hdpath + "0").getWallet();
var address = "0x" + wallet.getAddress().toString("hex");

var providerUrl = "https://testnet.infura.io";
var engine = new ProviderEngine();
engine.addProvider(new FilterSubprovider());
engine.addProvider(new WalletSubprovider(wallet, {}));
engine.addProvider(new Web3Subprovider(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider(providerUrl)));
engine.start(); // Required by the provider engine.

module.exports = {
  networks: {
    "ropsten": {
      network_id: 3,    // Official ropsten network id
      provider: engine, // Use our custom provider
      from: address    // Use the address we derived
    }
  },
  rpc: {
    // Use the default host and port when not using ropsten
    host: "localhost",
    port: 8545
  }
```

contracts/GustavoCoin.sol

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.11;

import 'zeppelin-solidity/contracts/token/MintableToken.sol';

contract GustavoCoin is MintableToken {
  string public name = "GUSTAVO COIN";
  string public symbol = "GUS";
  uint256 public decimals = 18;
}
```

contracts/GustavoCoinCrowdsale.sol

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.11;

import './GustavoCoin.sol';
import 'zeppelin-solidity/contracts/crowdsale/Crowdsale.sol';

contract GustavoCoinCrowdsale is Crowdsale {

  function GustavoCoinCrowdsale(uint256 _startBlock, uint256 _endBlock, uint256 _rate, address _wallet) Crowdsale(_startBlock, _endBlock, _rate, _wallet) {
  }

  function createTokenContract() internal returns (MintableToken) {
    return new GustavoCoin();
  }
}
```

migrations/2_deploy_contracts.js

```
var GustavoCoinCrowdsale = artifacts.require("./GustavoCoinCrowdsale.sol")

module.exports = function(deployer, network, accounts) {
  const startBlock = 1628404
  const endBlock = startBlock + 300
  const rate = new web3.BigNumber(1000)
  const wallet = "0x8005cEb675D2FF8c989CC95354438B9Fab568681"

  deployer.deploy(GustavoCoinCrowdsale, startBlock, endBlock, rate, wallet)
}
```

error

```
Running migration: 2_deploy_contracts.js
  Deploying GustavoCoinCrowdsale...
Error encountered, bailing. Network state unknown. Review successful transactions manually.
Error: The contract code couldn't be stored, please check your gas amount.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @gundas said on github, it worked after I used timestamp instead of block.

```
var GustavoCoinCrowdsale = artifacts.require("./GustavoCoinCrowdsale.sol")

module.exports = function(deployer, network, accounts) {
  const startTime = 1504859321
  const endTime = 1536395321
  const rate = new web3.BigNumber(1000)
  const wallet = "0x8005cEb675D2FF8c989CC95354438B9Fab568681"

  deployer.deploy(GustavoCoinCrowdsale, startTime, endTime, rate, wallet)
}
```

https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/zeppelin-solidity/issues/358