# Truffle does not work - could not find suitable configuration file

Tags: go-ethereum, truffle

I have searched some answers here and on google as well but none of them actually apply to my case.

I tried on console and power shell to run truffle migrate but I keep getting

```
could not find suitable configuration file
```

I saw that sometimes renaming the truffle-config.js is also an option but I just don't find this file on my computer even after running

```
npm install --force -g truffle
```

Any ideas of what could that be?

Comment: it worked in my case. https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/26012/is-it-possible-to-divide-my-crowdsale-contract-into-multiple-files-in-order-to-s

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Very noob mistake from my part.

I have actually to initialize the project before migrating it.

```
truffle init
```

after that

```
truffle migrate
```

sorry.

Comment: I made this noob mistake as well. I'm just starting out and wasn't in the correct directory.

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar issue. My problem was that my project (on the project root level) was missing a **truffle.js** file with the following contents:

```
module.exports = {
  networks: {
    development: {
      host: "127.0.0.1",
      port: 8545,
      network_id: "*" // Match any network id
    }
  }
};
```

[related truffle documentation](http://truffleframework.com/docs/advanced/configuration)

after adding this file my desired truffle commands worked

Answer (score 1):

I'm answering this question at a later date. I ran into the same issue, and in my case, none of the answers above was a solution for me.
I made a silly mistake, and that was executing `truffle console` in the wrong directory.

My solution was to run `truffle console` in the directory containing `truffle-config.js.`

Hopefully, anyone running into a similar issue might find this helpful sometimes.

Answer (score 1):

in my case I initialized truffle with "truffle init" in the same directory
in which i was working and then every truffle command started working.

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same problem but despite i had truffle-config file in root folder.

The problem that is was a `truffle-config.ts` not `truffle-config.js`.

Looks like truffle only works with JS config files.
Anyway wish this might help anyone )